# Mismatched input errors in antlr 3.5

Tags: antlr3

i have problems with my grammar code in antlr3.5 . My input file is

```
` define tcpChannel  ChannelName
        define 
          listener  
       ListnerProperty  
        end  
 listener ;

       define  
         execution 
            request   with   format   RequestFormat,
            response   with   format  ResponseFormat,
            error  with  format   ErrorFormat ,
            call  servicename.executionname
    end define execution ;

 end  
define channel ;
      `
```

My lexer code is as follows:

```
lexer grammar ChannelLexer;







// ***************** lexer rules:

Define
:
'define'
; 

Tcpchannel
:
'tcphannel'
;

Listener
:
'Listener'
;
End
:
'end'
;
Execution
:
' execution '
;
Request
:
' request '
;
With
:
' with '
;
Format
:
' format '
;
Response
:
' response '
;
Error
:
' error '
;
Call
:
' call '
;
Channel
:
' channel '
;

Dot
:
'.'
;

SColon
:
';'
;


Comma
:
','
;

Value
:
(
'a'..'z'
|'A'..'Z'
|'_'
)
(
'a'..'z'
|'A'..'Z'
|'_'
|Digit
)*
;




fragment
String
:
(
    '"'
    (
      ~(
        '"'
        | '\\'
       )
      | '\\'
      (
        '\\'
        | '"'
      )
    )*
    '"'
    | '\''
    (
      ~(
        '\''
        | '\\'
       )
      | '\\'
      (
        '\\'
        | '\''
      )
    )*
    '\''
  )
  {
  setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length() - 1).replaceAll("\\\\(.)",
      "$1"));

   }
   ;

   fragment
   Digit
   :
   '0'..'9'
;


Space
  :
  (
    ' '
    | '\t'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
    | '\u000C'
  )

   {
    skip();
   }
  ;
```

My parser code is:

```
parser grammar ChannelParser;

options
{
  // antlr will generate java lexer and parser
  language = Java;
  // generated parser should create abstract syntax tree
  output = AST;
}






// ***************** parser rules:
//our grammar accepts only salutation followed by an end symbol

expression
:

tcpChannelDefinition listenerDefinition  executionDefintion endchannel

;


tcpChannelDefinition
  :
  Define Tcpchannel channelName
  ;

channelName
  :
  i= Value
               {
                $i.setText("CHANNEL_NAME#" + $i.text);
               }
  ;

listenerDefinition
  :
  Define Listener listenerProperty endListener

  ;

listenerProperty
  :
  i=Value
            {
            $i.setText("PROPERTY_VALUE#" + $i.text);
            }

  ;

  endListener
  :
  End Listener SColon
  ;

executionDefintion
  :
     Define Execution execution 
  ;

execution
:
    Request With Format requestValue Comma
    Response With Format responseValue Comma
    Error With Format errorValue Comma
    Call servicename Dot executionname
;

requestValue
:
i=Value
  {
    $i.setText("REQUEST_FORMAT#" + $i.text);
    }

;  

responseValue
:
i=Value
 {
  $i.setText("RESPONSE_FORMAT#" + $i.text);
  }

; 

errorValue
:
i=Value
 {
   $i.setText("ERROR_FORMAT#" + $i.text);
  }

;

servicename
:
i=Value
  {
    $i.setText("SERVICE_NAME#" + $i.text);
     }

 ;

executionname
 :
 i=Value
  {
    $i.setText("OPERATION_NAME#" + $i.text);
    }

;

 endexecution
  :

 End Define Execution SColon
  ;

 endchannel
 :
 End Channel SColon

 ;
```

im getting error like missing Tcpchannel at 'tcpChannel' and extraneous input 'ChannelName' expecting Define. How to correct them. Please do help.ASAP

Comment: Be careful: rules are case sensitive. Imputs (following your grammar) are case sensitive too. Don't forget it ;)

Comment: Thank you Juan. but can you please find where Ive gone wrong. Im new to this and cant make out my error.

Comment: thanks juan.. i found out my error. Now what is 'no viable alternative at character ' error??

Comment: oh! I came late haha. Better if you found it by your own!! :) For your question, ANTLR parses your input "token by token". It tries to match your tokens with your grammar rules one-to-one. When it finds a token in a different order, you miss one token etc. It will throw you this exception. This is about structure, make sure your input and your grammar matches!! And.. as I told you, be careful with the case sensitive issue.

Comment: and juan, u have any idea how to create a AST tree out of this?

Comment: Yes, I've done it indeed. But it's impossible to explain this here in comments and it's out of the scope of the question. I recommend you to begin to work with it, take samples etc. And, if you have questions, don't hesitate to ask. I would be pleased to help you with whatever you need. ;)